Writing a libnss routines - Secondary groups don't show up when SSH is used
I've been working on a new project to expand the authentication options for Linux. Overall, the software is functional, but I am encountering unexpected results when groups are accessed through my libnss library.
I have a user whose primary group is "globalsudo". That user has a secondary group of "Development".  When I login via SSH, and run id,  this is my output.
$ id
uid=5000003(testuser) gid=2000032(globalsudo) groups=2000032(globalsudo)

Note the lack of "Development" listed as a secondary group.   However,  I can switch to the "Development" group using newgrp
$ newgrp Development
$ id
uid=5000003(testuser) gid=2000001(Development) groups=2000001(Development),2000032(globalsudo)

If I login on the Linux console, groups show up as expected.
$ id
uid=5000003(testuser) gid=2000032(globalsudo) groups=2000032(globalsudo),2000001(Development)

if I "sudo" as the user, the groups show up:
$ sudo -u testuser /bin/bash
$ id
uid=5000003(testuser) gid=2000032(globalsudo) groups=2000032(globalsudo),2000001(Development)

The only time secondary groups do not show up in commands like id, group, etc. is when I "ssh" into my test system!
Every other method of login works as I would expect.
I've been banging my head on this for several days.  Here's what I've tried.

My test platform is Debian 12 using OpenSSH_9.4p1

Yes, I've logged out and back in :)

In the /etc/ssh/sshd_config, I tried setting UsePAM yes and
UsePAM no. This did not affect the groups.

Commands like getent group,  getent group 2000001 and
getent group Development work as expected.

I've run sshd with debugging enabled,  but I don't see any
errors/warnings related to groups.  I do see sshd set the UID / GID
but no mention of secondary groups.

I've run some test code using initgroups() and that seems to
function fine.

I've messed with some PAM configs,  but I get the feeling groups
aren't set in PAM.  Also,  I would suspect that switching the
sshd_config UsePAM yes/no would change things but it does not.

I have changed the Development group to all lowercase, and that
did not have any effect.  The problem still exists.


While login, sudo, su, newgrp all work fine,  I get the feeling that the sshd process doesn't like how I'm presenting groups.  However,  without errors or warnings,  it's difficult for me to determine a good way to debug this issue.
Hopefully, this rambling post makes sense!  If needed,  I can post my libnss library source code.
Edit:

While still using my NSS module,  if I add a user to a secondary
group via the /etc/group, that works as expected with SSH.
My library is getting group information via an API call.


I am thinking that you do not load the interactive session, I mean su - user  or sudo -i which could also have a similar behavior over ssh even if you don't develop a new library

Where does your nss module get its data from? Does it use a local source, or a proxy daemon for network access, or direct network access from the module?

Thank you for the responses.   My library calls an API to retrieve group information.  I should also point out that if I add secondary groups to a user via the /etc/group file,  that works fine with sshd.
